# How to create temporary table in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql

create temporary table deprecated in mysql 5.7. But I need to create temporary table. So what can I do ?

I have tried with:

```
create temporary table temp_users select * from users
```

Comment: _create temporary table deprecated_ **No its not!** Do you mean this statement `Support for TABLESPACE = innodb_file_per_table and TABLESPACE = innodb_temporary clauses with CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE is deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.24 and will be removed in a future version of MySQL.`

Comment: What is the problem or error message, when you try to use the query from your question?